# Injecting io dispatcher in Application using hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

I created something like this.

```
import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp
import com.example.data.feature.common.preference.PreferenceRepository
import javax.inject.Inject
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication : Application() {
    @Inject lateinit var preferenceRepository: PreferenceRepository

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        resetPreference()
    }

    fun resetPreference() = GlobalScope.launch{
        preferenceRepository.putManagerInfo("")
    }
}
```

```
import javax.inject.Qualifier

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class DefaultDispatcher

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class IoDispatcher

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class MainDispatcher

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
@Qualifier
annotation class MainImmediateDispatcher
```

```
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.SupervisorJob

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object CoroutinesScopesModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesCoroutineScope(
        @DefaultDispatcher defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
    ): CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + defaultDispatcher)
}
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object CoroutinesDispatchersModule {
    @DefaultDispatcher
    @Provides
    fun providesDefaultDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default

    @IoDispatcher
    @Provides
    fun providesIoDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO

    @MainDispatcher
    @Provides
    fun providesMainDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main

    @MainImmediateDispatcher
    @Provides
    fun providesMainImmediateDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main.immediate
}
```

but I'd like to avoid GlobalScope in the Application class. How can I solve this issue? I need to use IO scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ProcessLifecycleOwner` for the `lifecycle` and `lifecycScope` of the process.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner

```
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycleScope.launch([YOUR_DISPATCHER_HERE]) {
  //task
}
```

You need to add the below dependency with other lifecycle dependencies -

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version")
```

To inject your Dispatcher -

```
@IoDispatcher
@Inject lateinit var ioDispacher: CoroutineDispatcher
```

Comment: `ProcessLifecycleOwner` is interesting. So, it's cancelable and it's cancel and resume automatically by the activity lifecycle?

Comment: It's not Activity's lifecycle. It is the lifecycle of the Application itself and it can be used instead of GlobalScope.

Comment: I added ioDispacher in the [YOUR_DISPATCHER_HERE]. But it gives me redline, it says it requires CoroutineContext but it's dispatchers.

Comment: I changed `Dispatchers` to `CoroutineDispatcher` and the redline is gone. Is that correct approach?

Comment: But I am curious that the reason why I separated the dispatchers and make it to inject is for testing and If I annotate `@IoDispatcher` does it affect the test? It looks like the dispatcher is fixed. Can I inject different Dispatcher in ui test or unit test? @Naresh

Comment: @IoDispatcher is a Qualifier in Dagger. You should learn more about how Qualifiers work in Dagger, that will help you for their different use cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252806/discussion-between-c-an-and-naresh-nk).